# Unwanted <param0> node from PHP SoapClient non-wsdl mode

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to make a request with the PHP SoapClient in non-WSDL mode. I'm passing parameters as a multi-dimensional object as shown in the below code snippet:

```
$params = new stdClass;
$params->Characteristic = new stdClass;
$params->Characteristic->Name = 'PRODUCT_TYPE';
$params->Characteristic->CharacteristicValue = new stdClass;
$params->Characteristic->CharacteristicValue->Value = $type;
$params->Characteristic->CharacteristicValue->Type = 'STRING';

$client = new SoapClient(NULL, array(   'trace' => true,  'exceptions' => true, 'uri' => $uri, 'location' => $location,
        'connection_timeout'=>9999, 
        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS, 
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1', 
        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL
    ));

$response = $client->thisIsTheFunction($params);
```

The generated XML is almost right apart from being wrapped in a  tag:

```
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://[removed]">
    <soap-env:body>
        <ns1:thisisthefunction>
            <param0>
                <characteristic>
                    <name>PRODUCT_TYPE</name>
                    <characteristicvalue>
                        <value>Adhoc</value>
                        <type>STRING</type>
                    </characteristicvalue>
                </characteristic>
            </param0>
        </ns1:thisisthefunction>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

The problem is this is being detected as malformed by the service.  Is there any way we can remove this extra  tag?

Comment: Could you please tell, what is value of `$uri`, `$location`, `$value` ?

Comment: Hi Log1c.  $uri is the namespace, $location is the endpoint and $type = 'STRING'.  I cannot reveal the first 2 because they are confidential.  But I don't think it matters does it?  Thanks

Comment: Anyone have any ideas???

Comment: What I can guess is, its because of multiple parameter support. If there are multiple parameters it will grow like `<param0>..</parm0> <param1>..</param1>..` and so on

Answer (score 3):

I think if you want remove param0 and put characteristicValue in this place, you need to use a SoapParam (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapparam.php).

In fact, your call must proceed like that :

```
$response = $client->thisIsTheFunction(new SoapParam($params->Characteristic, 'ns1:Characteristic'));
```

Now, your generated XML looks like that :

```
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://[removed]">
<soap-env:body>
    <ns1:thisisthefunction>
        <ns1:characteristic>
            <name>PRODUCT_TYPE</name>
            <characteristicvalue>
                <value>Adhoc</value>
                <type>STRING</type>
             </characteristicvalue>
        </ns1:characteristic>
    </ns1:thisisthefunction>
</soap-env:body>
```

Good luck !

Comment: Another examples here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928169/php-soap-non-wsdl-call-how-do-you-pass-parameters