# Incorrect SOAP request format for the message body using __soapcall() PHP

Tags: php, soap, request, format

I have used  __soapcall() to send a soap requsest.

```
     $parameters = array(
        'ID' => '0001',
        'TimeStamp' => '2016-06-20T17:03:27Z',
        'SenderID' => 'B2eww8',

    );

    $URL = 'https://example.com';

    $client = new \SoapClient(null, array(
        'location' => $URL,
        'uri' => "http://example.com/SOAP/WSDL/abc.xsd",
        'trace' => 1

    ));

     $return = $client->__soapCall("TestSoapRequest", $parameters);

   var_dump($return);
```

Then request looks like.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:TestSoapRequest>
        <param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">0001</param2>
        <param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">2016-06-20T17:03:27Z</param3>
        <param2 xsi:type="xsd:string">B2eww8</param4>
     </ns1:TestSoapRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

But desired format is,

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:TestSoapRequest xmlns:ns1="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd">
        <ID>0001</ID>
        <TimeStamp>2014-05-22T17:03:27Z</TimeStamp>
        <SenderID>B2eww8</SenderID>
        </ns1:TestSoapRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

How can i achive this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition for `TestSoapRequest` in http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd so if you want to prepare request without it then you should use `SoapParam` class described here http://php.net/manual/en/soapparam.soapparam.php

Similar problem has been described here [PHP Soap non-WSDL call: how do you pass parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928169/php-soap-non-wsdl-call-how-do-you-pass-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I had the same problem and was using an XML document. I created a generator file which creates an XML document with structure corrected.

```
    $XMLDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $Body = $XMLDocument->createElement('soapenv:Body', null);
    $Body->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:ns1', "http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd");

    $TestSoapRequest = $XMLDocument->createElement('TestSoapRequest', null);

    $element = $XMLDocument->createElement('ID', '0001');
    $TestSoapRequest->appendChild($grossWeightElement);
    
    $element = $XMLDocument->createElement('TimeStamp', '2014-05-22T17:03:27Z');
    $TestSoapRequest->appendChild($grossWeightElement);
    
    $element = $XMLDocument->createElement('SenderID', 'B2eww8');
    $TestSoapRequest->appendChild($grossWeightElement);
```